# Problema na inserção de valores num array/list

Tags: kotlin

Estou tentando fazer uma inserção de número numa lista/array mas na condição **if** está dizendo: **No get method providing array access**

```kotlin
import java.util.Scanner

fun main(){

    val input = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var num:Int

    for(i in  0 until 5){
        println("Insira um numero entre 0 e 10: ")
        num  = input.nextInt()

        if(num[i]<0 or num[i]>10{
            println("INVALIDO")
        }else{
            i++
        }

    }

    for(i in num) print(i)
}
```

Comment: `num` é um inteiro e não uma lista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Num geral, sua lógica não faz muito sentido.

Você precisa criar uma lista para armazenar os números e, ao invés disso, está tentando acessar índices em uma variável do tipo `Int`.

Você precisa de, basicamente, isto:

```kotlin
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {

    val input = Scanner(System.`in`)

    // Criar uma lista para armazenar todos os números
    var listaNumeros = mutableListOf<Int>()

    for(i in 0 until 5){
        println("Insira um numero entre 0 e 10: ")
        
        // Essa variável vai receber cada input do usuário
        val num = input.nextInt()

        // A validação precisa ser no valor que o usuário digitou
        if(num < 0 || num > 10) {
            println("INVALIDO")
            continue // Continua o loop caso a validação falhe
        }

        // Adiciona o número na lista
        listaNumeros.add(num)
    }

    for(i in listaNumeros) print(i)
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado, me ajudou muito, pois estava muito confuso de como fazia

Comment: Leia [este material](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/) pra entender como funcionam as coleções no Kotlin.